# How to kill a contract in ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, selfdestruct, immutability

I'm trying to kill this contract

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2016-08-31
*/

//sol Wallet
// Multi-sig, daily-limited account proxy/wallet.
// @authors:
// Gav Wood <g@ethdev.com>
// inheritable "property" contract that enables methods to be protected by requiring the acquiescence of either a
// single, or, crucially, each of a number of, designated owners.
// usage:
// use modifiers onlyowner (just own owned) or onlymanyowners(hash), whereby the same hash must be provided by
// some number (specified in constructor) of the set of owners (specified in the constructor, modifiable) before the
// interior is executed.
contract multiowned {

    // TYPES

    // struct for the status of a pending operation.
    struct PendingState {
        uint yetNeeded;
        uint ownersDone;
        uint index;
    }

    // EVENTS

    // this contract only has five types of events: it can accept a confirmation, in which case
    // we record owner and operation (hash) alongside it.
    event Confirmation(address owner, bytes32 operation);
    event Revoke(address owner, bytes32 operation);
    // some others are in the case of an owner changing.
    event OwnerChanged(address oldOwner, address newOwner);
    event OwnerAdded(address newOwner);
    event OwnerRemoved(address oldOwner);
    // the last one is emitted if the required signatures change
    event RequirementChanged(uint newRequirement);

    // MODIFIERS

    // simple single-sig function modifier.
    modifier onlyowner {
        if (isOwner(msg.sender))
            _
    }
    // multi-sig function modifier: the operation must have an intrinsic hash in order
    // that later attempts can be realised as the same underlying operation and
    // thus count as confirmations.
    modifier onlymanyowners(bytes32 _operation) {
        if (confirmAndCheck(_operation))
            _
    }

    // METHODS

    // constructor is given number of sigs required to do protected "onlymanyowners" transactions
    // as well as the selection of addresses capable of confirming them.
    function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) {
        m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1;
        m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender);
        m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1;
        for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i)
        {
            m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]);
            m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i;
        }
        m_required = _required;
    }

    // Revokes a prior confirmation of the given operation
    function revoke(bytes32 _operation) external {
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)];
        // make sure they're an owner
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return;
        uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex;
        var pending = m_pending[_operation];
        if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit > 0) {
            pending.yetNeeded++;
            pending.ownersDone -= ownerIndexBit;
            Revoke(msg.sender, _operation);
        }
    }

    // Replaces an owner `_from` with another `_to`.
    function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        if (isOwner(_to)) return;
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)];
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return;

        clearPending();
        m_owners[ownerIndex] = uint(_to);
        m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)] = 0;
        m_ownerIndex[uint(_to)] = ownerIndex;
        OwnerChanged(_from, _to);
    }

    function addOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        if (isOwner(_owner)) return;

        clearPending();
        if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners)
            reorganizeOwners();
        if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners)
            return;
        m_numOwners++;
        m_owners[m_numOwners] = uint(_owner);
        m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = m_numOwners;
        OwnerAdded(_owner);
    }

    function removeOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)];
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return;
        if (m_required > m_numOwners - 1) return;

        m_owners[ownerIndex] = 0;
        m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = 0;
        clearPending();
        reorganizeOwners(); //make sure m_numOwner is equal to the number of owners and always points to the optimal free slot
        OwnerRemoved(_owner);
    }

    function changeRequirement(uint _newRequired) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        if (_newRequired > m_numOwners) return;
        m_required = _newRequired;
        clearPending();
        RequirementChanged(_newRequired);
    }

    function isOwner(address _addr) returns (bool) {
        return m_ownerIndex[uint(_addr)] > 0;
    }

    function hasConfirmed(bytes32 _operation, address _owner) constant returns (bool) {
        var pending = m_pending[_operation];
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)];

        // make sure they're an owner
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return false;

        // determine the bit to set for this owner.
        uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex;
        if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // INTERNAL METHODS

    function confirmAndCheck(bytes32 _operation) internal returns (bool) {
        // determine what index the present sender is:
        uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)];
        // make sure they're an owner
        if (ownerIndex == 0) return;

        var pending = m_pending[_operation];
        // if we're not yet working on this operation, switch over and reset the confirmation status.
        if (pending.yetNeeded == 0) {
            // reset count of confirmations needed.
            pending.yetNeeded = m_required;
            // reset which owners have confirmed (none) - set our bitmap to 0.
            pending.ownersDone = 0;
            pending.index = m_pendingIndex.length++;
            m_pendingIndex[pending.index] = _operation;
        }
        // determine the bit to set for this owner.
        uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex;
        // make sure we (the message sender) haven't confirmed this operation previously.
        if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) {
            Confirmation(msg.sender, _operation);
            // ok - check if count is enough to go ahead.
            if (pending.yetNeeded <= 1) {
                // enough confirmations: reset and run interior.
                delete m_pendingIndex[m_pending[_operation].index];
                delete m_pending[_operation];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // not enough: record that this owner in particular confirmed.
                pending.yetNeeded--;
                pending.ownersDone |= ownerIndexBit;
            }
        }
    }

    function reorganizeOwners() private returns (bool) {
        uint free = 1;
        while (free < m_numOwners)
        {
            while (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[free] != 0) free++;
            while (m_numOwners > 1 && m_owners[m_numOwners] == 0) m_numOwners--;
            if (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[m_numOwners] != 0 && m_owners[free] == 0)
            {
                m_owners[free] = m_owners[m_numOwners];
                m_ownerIndex[m_owners[free]] = free;
                m_owners[m_numOwners] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function clearPending() internal {
        uint length = m_pendingIndex.length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            if (m_pendingIndex[i] != 0)
                delete m_pending[m_pendingIndex[i]];
        delete m_pendingIndex;
    }

    // FIELDS

    // the number of owners that must confirm the same operation before it is run.
    uint public m_required;
    // pointer used to find a free slot in m_owners
    uint public m_numOwners;

    // list of owners
    uint[256] m_owners;
    uint constant c_maxOwners = 250;
    // index on the list of owners to allow reverse lookup
    mapping(uint => uint) m_ownerIndex;
    // the ongoing operations.
    mapping(bytes32 => PendingState) m_pending;
    bytes32[] m_pendingIndex;
}

// inheritable "property" contract that enables methods to be protected by placing a linear limit (specifiable)
// on a particular resource per calendar day. is multiowned to allow the limit to be altered. resource that method
// uses is specified in the modifier.
contract daylimit is multiowned {

    // MODIFIERS

    // simple modifier for daily limit.
    modifier limitedDaily(uint _value) {
        if (underLimit(_value))
            _
    }

    // METHODS

    // constructor - stores initial daily limit and records the present day's index.
    function daylimit(uint _limit) {
        m_dailyLimit = _limit;
        m_lastDay = today();
    }
    // (re)sets the daily limit. needs many of the owners to confirm. doesn't alter the amount already spent today.
    function setDailyLimit(uint _newLimit) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        m_dailyLimit = _newLimit;
    }
    // (re)sets the daily limit. needs many of the owners to confirm. doesn't alter the amount already spent today.
    function resetSpentToday() onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        m_spentToday = 0;
    }

    // INTERNAL METHODS

    // checks to see if there is at least `_value` left from the daily limit today. if there is, subtracts it and
    // returns true. otherwise just returns false.
    function underLimit(uint _value) internal onlyowner returns (bool) {
        // reset the spend limit if we're on a different day to last time.
        if (today() > m_lastDay) {
            m_spentToday = 0;
            m_lastDay = today();
        }
        // check to see if there's enough left - if so, subtract and return true.
        if (m_spentToday + _value >= m_spentToday && m_spentToday + _value <= m_dailyLimit) {
            m_spentToday += _value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // determines today's index.
    function today() private constant returns (uint) { return now / 1 days; }

    // FIELDS

    uint public m_dailyLimit;
    uint public m_spentToday;
    uint public m_lastDay;
}

// interface contract for multisig proxy contracts; see below for docs.
contract multisig {

    // EVENTS

    // logged events:
    // Funds has arrived into the wallet (record how much).
    event Deposit(address from, uint value);
    // Single transaction going out of the wallet (record who signed for it, how much, and to whom it's going).
    event SingleTransact(address owner, uint value, address to, bytes data);
    // Multi-sig transaction going out of the wallet (record who signed for it last, the operation hash, how much, and to whom it's going).
    event MultiTransact(address owner, bytes32 operation, uint value, address to, bytes data);
    // Confirmation still needed for a transaction.
    event ConfirmationNeeded(bytes32 operation, address initiator, uint value, address to, bytes data);

    // FUNCTIONS

    // TODO: document
    function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) external;
    function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external returns (bytes32);
    function confirm(bytes32 _h) returns (bool);
}

// usage:
// bytes32 h = Wallet(w).from(oneOwner).transact(to, value, data);
// Wallet(w).from(anotherOwner).confirm(h);
contract Wallet is multisig, multiowned, daylimit {

    uint public version = 2;

    // TYPES

    // Transaction structure to remember details of transaction lest it need be saved for a later call.
    struct Transaction {
        address to;
        uint value;
        bytes data;
    }

    // METHODS

    // constructor - just pass on the owner array to the multiowned and
    // the limit to daylimit
    function Wallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit)
            multiowned(_owners, _required) daylimit(_daylimit) {
    }

    // kills the contract sending everything to `_to`.
    function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        suicide(_to);
    }

    // gets called when no other function matches
    function() {
        // just being sent some cash?
        if (msg.value > 0)
            Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    // Outside-visible transact entry point. Executes transacion immediately if below daily spend limit.
    // If not, goes into multisig process. We provide a hash on return to allow the sender to provide
    // shortcuts for the other confirmations (allowing them to avoid replicating the _to, _value
    // and _data arguments). They still get the option of using them if they want, anyways.
    function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external onlyowner returns (bytes32 _r) {
        // first, take the opportunity to check that we're under the daily limit.
        if (underLimit(_value)) {
            SingleTransact(msg.sender, _value, _to, _data);
            // yes - just execute the call.
            _to.call.value(_value)(_data);
            return 0;
        }
        // determine our operation hash.
        _r = sha3(msg.data, block.number);
        if (!confirm(_r) && m_txs[_r].to == 0) {
            m_txs[_r].to = _to;
            m_txs[_r].value = _value;
            m_txs[_r].data = _data;
            ConfirmationNeeded(_r, msg.sender, _value, _to, _data);
        }
    }

    // confirm a transaction through just the hash. we use the previous transactions map, m_txs, in order
    // to determine the body of the transaction from the hash provided.
    function confirm(bytes32 _h) onlymanyowners(_h) returns (bool) {
        if (m_txs[_h].to != 0) {
            m_txs[_h].to.call.value(m_txs[_h].value)(m_txs[_h].data);
            MultiTransact(msg.sender, _h, m_txs[_h].value, m_txs[_h].to, m_txs[_h].data);
            delete m_txs[_h];
            return true;
        }
    }

    // INTERNAL METHODS

    function clearPending() internal {
        uint length = m_pendingIndex.length;
        for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            delete m_txs[m_pendingIndex[i]];
        super.clearPending();
    }

    // FIELDS

    // pending transactions we have at present.
    mapping (bytes32 => Transaction) m_txs;
}
```

I'm trying to use the Ethereum Wallet or MyCrypto in order to recover the funds and kill the contract.

I tried to execute a withdrawal but I only got more coins on it :S

As you can see I am a totally newbie on this and I'm trying to just stay with the wallet and forget about the contract.

Whenever I try to use the function kill I got this message:

```
Error executing contract method hasConfirmed:  {}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you cannot do anything to/with a smart contract unless the contract was programmed to implement it. That includes killing it.

If a contract has "kill" capability, it will be coded using `selfdestruct`. A close cousin is the Pausable pattern, which is preferable in most instances. https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5

From eyeballing the code, I did not see `selfdestruct` or `Pausable`.

If I am right and no such functions are coded, then the contract cannot be stopped. It's important to understand that a key benefit of Ethereum "contracts" is their immutible nature. They cannot be stopped. This provides users with assurance that the rules will not be changed. As a developer, it is important to come to grips with important implications. There will often be no way to correct even a serious problem.

Since you are constrained by the functions in the contract and since the transactions are irreversible, I might suggest you rephrase the question with a more comprehensive description of the situation. Possibly someone will help you work out a feasible course of action.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob,

Thank you for you answer, sorry for my bad English as this is not my mother language, what I'm really trying to do is to recover the ether I have in this contract.

As far as I know the function:
`// kills the contract sending everything to `_to`.
    function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
        suicide(_to);
    }`
Should be enough to recover the ETH in the owner wallet(my wallet as I'm the owner) and kill the contract.

I hope it is more understandable now.

Regards.

Comment: That's a weird way to code it. We would need to see `modifier onlymanyowners {` to be sure we don't mislead. It looks like you have to have knowledge of a secret and also the block when the transaction is mined (doesn't seem very smart) you will have to create a special message.

Comment: This is the contact address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x01ea452df789bd68c0e06e35225140c4043153df

There we can find the contract creation: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x79cec8b390c426caf11a6717019705e397bda0870033569763673a0a3123e199

But I have no idea of any secret other than my private key or the wallet password.